# tf.train.batch - Get items from dequeue_many operation

Tags: tensorflow

For my TensorFlow training pipeline I am using a `tf.FIFOQueue` containing image files to read and a `tf.train.batch` to obtain a batch of pre-processed images. This works fine.

For debugging purposes, I am now looking for a way to get the filenames that were fetched from the `dequeue_many` operation in `tf.train.batch`.

Below the corresponding piece of my code. So I am trying to get the `str` or `tf.string` objects from the `filename_queue` that are dequeued inside the batch operation. If there any solution besides rewriting a `tf.train.batch` like operation and perform the `dequeue_many` operation myself?

```
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(100000, [tf.string], shapes=[[]])

# ...

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_raw = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw, channels=3)

# Image preprocessing
image_preproc = ...

# Read a batch of preprocessing images from queue
image_batch = tf.train.batch([image_preproc], batch_size, num_threads=1)

# How to get the filenames corresponding to the images in 'image_batch'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get something from the `key` returned by [`read`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/WholeFileReader#read).

```
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(100000, [tf.string], shapes=[[]])

# ...

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
image_key, image_raw = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw, channels=3)

# Image preprocessing
image_preproc = ...

# Read a batch of preprocessing images from queue
image_batch, image_key_batch = tf.train.batch([image_preproc, image_key],
                                              batch_size, num_threads=1)
```

Comment: Thanks jdehesa for your answer! Using the `key` of  `reader.read()` was indeed the solution I was looking for. The documentation of this TF function could be improved though. My final solution to get the filenames for the entire batch is here: https://gist.github.com/tomrunia/700585a0d44dff4606f26b7b50856932

Comment: @verified.human Yes, the documentation, which uses the abstract (and somewhat cryptic) term `key` seems to be just inherited from the parent class [`tf.ReaderBase`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ReaderBase), which is more generic and not specific to file reading.